# How to choose data from vaules in android

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Hi i have some data in values that structured in this way every time i generate random number and i want to show values of that number from values
what is the solution

```
  <string name="info47">hello world</string>
    <string name="info48">hello dolly</string>

    int ok=47;
  infotextView.setText(getString(R.string.info{ok}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

If in activity like MainActivity you can use this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int ok=47;
    String name="info"+ok;
    TextView infotextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    infotextView.setText(getStringByName(this,name));
}

public static String getStringByName(Context context, String name) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    return res.getString(res.getIdentifier(name, "string", context.getPackageName()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
<string-array name="info">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
</string-array>

String [] infoArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.info);
int randomNumber = 1; // Place your random number here
String value = infoArray[randomNumber];
```